# Erro ao retornar valor de uma query com php e ajax (Request failed: parsererror)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estou tentando retornar o resultado de uma query via ajax com php e jquery, porém não está funcionando, recebo uma mensagem de erro de parser e não estou conseguindo identificar o problema.

FUNCAO JS

```
function buscaCliente() {
    var cnpj = $('#cnpjCliente').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "buscaCliente.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {'cnpj':cnpj},
        dataType: "JSON"

    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

    }).always(function() {
        console.log("completou");
    });
  }
```

BUSCACLIENTE.PHP

```
<?php 

require_once 'pdo.php';

$cnpjCliente = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'cnpj');

$sql = "SELECT nome
        FROM php.clientes 
        WHERE cnpj = ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$cnpjCliente]);

$nome = $stmt->fetch();

echo json_encode($nome);

?>
```

MENSAGEM DE ERRO

Request failed: parsererror

Comment: Se possível exiba o erro que está retornando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a conversão do JSON com `$.parseJSON(response)` e remova o `dataType: "JSON"` do `$.ajax`. ficando assim:

```
function buscaCliente() {
  var cnpj = $('#cnpjCliente').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "buscaCliente.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {'cnpj':cnpj}
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log($.parseJSON(response));

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

  }).always(function() {
    console.log("completou");
  });
}
```